# Trouble accessing jQuery plugin properties

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm having trouble accessing plugin variables defined inside prototype object.
Please take a look at this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5Mx2F/).

Most of the code is plain and simple just focus these two functions:

```
    add: function(){
        self.counter++;
        console.log(self.counter);
    },

    getCounter: function(){
        $(".result").text(self.counter);
        console.log(self.counter);
    }
```

As you can see `add` method is simply adding numbers each time it gets called.

The problem i'm having is if i call `getCounter` method like this

```
$(".test").inlineTag("getCounter");
```

It will always return 0 even if `counter` isn't 0.

This wont make much sense without looking at my jsfiddle example so please do that and let me know what's wrong, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra "." in your markup, it should read

```
<div class="result">0</div>
```

instead of

```
<div class=".result">0</div>
```